# \documentclass{book} \usepackage{siunitx} \begin{document} hi \end{document}

Tags: compiling, siunitx

I have a problem, the following code won't compile:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

I have tried reinstalling the "siunitx " package with no success. (I need was writing a document and managed to identify this package as causing the issue.).

Any ideas? Error in TexStudio (with the username starred out)

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 
"document".tex

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains 
the information to get MiKTeX going again: 
C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may 
want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 
"document".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Never mind, I've mangaged to fix the issue. I looked at the log file for the latest entry (scroll to the bottom). It was trying to install a package called beamer, triggered by "translator.sty". I already had beamer installed, but I did not have translator installed. After installing translator, it appears to work.

Comment: Erh, how is `beamer` related to the mwe you posted? If it turned out to be just a user error (a missing package), you might want to delete your question as it probably will not help future visitors.

Comment: @slew123 Can you convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @daleif siunitx loads the translator package, which was recently moved into a separate package from beamer. This problem can very well happen to other siunitx users, so the information to update the tex distribution or to install the package could help. (same problem was also seen with several miktex beamer users who had to uninstall beamer and only the reinstall triggered the installation of translator)

Comment: You should probably synchronize your package database (in the package manager(s) (admin and user), menu repositories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously the `translator` package, which is loaded by `siuntx` was part of the `beamer` package. At one point it became an independent package.

This sometimes caused problems for miktex users, as miktex sometimes failed to automatically install it (maybe because it thought it was already installed as part of beamer?). Uninstalling and reinstalling of `beamer` was reported to help, same as explicitly installing `translator`.